# Is it impossible to practically predict the future?

Tags: universe, information

For the sake of curiosity, let us postulate a universe that can be completely described by mathematics. Let us further postulate, that humankind has fully discovered all the fundamental laws of nature. Now scientists want to build a machine in order to [predict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictability) the future.

Consider this: Let the data describing the instantaneous state of the universe be $X$. How can we possibly contain $X$, when $X$ would contain the container containing $X$ (and therefore containing itself)?

This sounds like an infinitely recursive data set.

Comment: I suggest you take a look to [Russell's antinomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_paradox). It is to avoid such antinomies that the axioms of set theory explicitly prohibit the existence of such sets as you propose. These collections are often called classes, but they are not completely formalized, so are not very manageable mathematical objects.

Comment: Conventional quantum mechanics is an obvious counterexample to that. Philosophers need to stop fighting the lost fights of the 19th century over and over again.

Answer (score -4):

We can predict what is more probable to happen. Our mathematical models do not describe the nature exactly. For example, consider angular velocity, defined as  $\omega=2\pi/T$, where $T$ is the period.

We can only estimate the value of $\omega$ of any rotary system because we don't know the exact value of $\pi$.

Comment: This does not answer my question.